# Embed an application within a WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms, user-interface

I'm working in Visual Studio 2015, in C # and WPF technology. I need to embed to a window of my program, another window system of a third party system, such as Notepad.

I found the answer [here](http://www.elguille.info/NET/dotnet/setParentNET.aspx) (sorry the site is in spanish) but it only works with Windows Form.

This is my code.

```
//get the third party window
public static IntPtr getWindow(string titleName)
{
   Process[] pros = Process.GetProcesses(".");
   foreach (Process p in pros)
      if (p.MainWindowTitle.ToUpper().Contains(titleName.ToUpper()))
         return p.MainWindowHandle;
      return new IntPtr();
}

//Get my own window
IntPtr ptr = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;

//a window embedded within the other
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public extern static IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWnChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

As I said, that works for Windows Forms, but in WPF doesn't work.

Comment: You are almost there, you should just put the code together correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code, the problem was that you need to set position, width, height and repaint the child window in the new parent window.

```
public void CapturarApp()
        {
            hWndApp = ScreenFuntion.getWindow("Notepad");
            if (hWndApp.ToInt32() > 0)
            {
                ProgramsEncrustForm.MoveWindow(hWndApp,
                    0, 0,
                    Int32.Parse(Width.ToString()),
                    Int32.Parse(Height.ToString()), 1);
                ProgramsEncrustForm.SetParent(hWndApp, new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
            }
            else
            {
                hWndApp = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            this.Show();
        }
```

And here is the method to move and repaint the window

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public extern static int MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y,
    int nWidth, int nHeight, int bRepaint);
```

Comment: I believe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40410219/3110834) answers your question and also the comment addresses the issue which *You may also want to re-position notepad after you added it to your window. You can use SetWindowPos method for this purpose*. In such cases having a complete answer you don't need to post your own answer you can post some comments about how to apply the solution since the one who answered your question have said *Let me know if you have any problem applying the solution*. I also added `SetWindowPos` to the answer.